# How can I get a number that is associated with a specific record from the database?

Tags: database, linq

How can I get a number that is associated with a specific record from the database?

What I want is to pluck the single number that is the department id and I’ve tried

```
 var course = from c in db.Courses where c.Title == courseTitle[indiciesOfSelectedCourses[sc]] select c.DepartmentID;
```

Then I tried something like this:

```
 int inn =Convert.ToInt32(course.FirstOrDefault());
```

also tried  other methods but there is always a Linq error.  How can I get just the unique number that is associated with a specific course title in this call?

Comment: What's the error? Would make it a lot easier to identify the problem.

Comment: What type does that make `course`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query returns department ids of all courses matching your criteria. You can select FirstOrDefault id

```
 var id = (from c in db.Courses 
           where c.Title == courseTitle[indiciesOfSelectedCourses[sc]] 
           select c.DepartmentID).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or better select first or default course and then get id if course is not null

```
 var title = courseTitle[indiciesOfSelectedCourses[sc]];
 var course = db.Courses.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Title == title);

 if (course != null)
 {
     var id = course.DepartmentID;
     // ...
 }
```

Or if there can be many matching courses, then you can enumerate results:

```
 var ids = from c in db.Courses 
           where c.Title == courseTitle[indiciesOfSelectedCourses[sc]] 
           select c.DepartmentID;

 foreach(var id in ids)
    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey, I used the second method and it works perfectly.  Thanks again!!!